# Road to Kuiper's theorem

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, k-theory

I was scrolling through wikipedia whilst procrastinating some homework and landed on [Kuiper's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuiper%27s_theorem), the statement being that GL(H) is weakly contractible, with H a infinite dimensional Hilbert space

In so far as I understand this theorem, it is extremly cool. 
However it is a bit too advanced for me to figure out how to get to understanding this theorem. What subject does it belong to? What are the prerequisites? In what subjects can it be used?

I was hoping that you guys can give me an answer which would be clearer, and more self contained, than just simply skipping from link to link

Comment: Kuiper proved many wonderful theorems.

Comment: I edited my question so that people can know which theorem I am talking about